# How can I make a function in Javascript global to my html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First, I appreciate any direction given.... Let me preface this by saying, I am learning Javascript and HTML.

My problem is that I am trying to call my function to update audio time like so:

```
<audio id="track" preload="auto" type="audio/mpeg" ontimeupdate="displayTime(this)">
            <source src="mp3/mysong.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
            Unsupported audio format!
        </audio>
```

My function is in the Javascript IFFE function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 ... /*Global Variables*/

 ...

 function displayTime(event) {

            sec = Math.floor(event.duration);
            min = Math.floor(sec / 60);
            min = min >= 10 ? min : '0' + min;
            sec = Math.floor(sec % 60);
            sec = sec >= 10 ? sec : '0' + sec;


            ct_sec = Math.floor(event.currentTime);
            ct_min = Math.floor(ct_sec / 60);
            ct_min = ct_min >= 10 ? ct_min : '0' + ct_min;
            ct_sec = Math.floor(ct_sec % 60);
            ct_sec = ct_sec >= 10 ? ct_sec : '0' + ct_sec;


            document.getElementById('ticker').innerHTML = ct_min + ":" + ct_sec + "-" + min + ":" + sec;

        }



});
```

Can anyone advise on why I get the error function displayTime(this) not defined? I also tried using window.myFunction to try to make it global to the dom ... to no avail.

Comment: Assigning to a `window` property is the right thing to do. If that didn't work, you didn't do it properly, but since you didn't post that code nobody can say why.

Comment: For extra credit, have a look at the native and JQuery way of events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener and http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: You could also register the event in the ready function! by doing `$(document).on('timeupdate", "#track", displayTime)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because it's not visible outside the scope of the function.

After the declaration assign the reference of the function to the global object

```
window.displayTime = displayTime;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! ...accepting your answer as soon as it let me.

Answer (score 1):

Anything in the `document.ready` handler will be put inside of that function's scope.  Thus, if you want the function to be declared global from within the scope, you need to declare it in the global scope, and then you may use it with the `window.` prefix.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 ... /*Global Variables*/
window.displayTime = function (event) { ... }
});
```

Usage:

```
<button onclick="window.displayTime()">test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to making the function global, you could also attach the event listener via JavaScript like this:

```
$('#track').on('timeupdate', displayTime);
```